# Excel formatting without VBA

Tags: excel

So I have some results which may or may not have totals. In this case food. Each food is given an amount and a weight total. I have information below the results however which I do not want to shift. I would use a table however, if I hide rows, it shifts items up. If I sort the rows, the name of the food with no results will still show. Any idea how I could reformat my results into food with results only in a new referenced cell? I'm trying to automate this with no button pressing, and without using macro's/vba's. I could use something like `=IF(ISBLANK(B21),"noResults",A21)` but how could i list them all like my example blelow?

```
       a1    b1      c1 

           Amount   Weight
x    Apples   5     10
x    Oranges        
x    Peaches  6     10
x    Lemons   2     10
x    Tomatos        
x    Avacados 3     10
x
x
x    xxxxdon't shift or move xxxxxxxxx
```

TO:

```
x    g1      h1     i1
x            Amount Weight
x    Apples   5     10
x    Peaches  6     10
x    Lemons   2     10  
x    Avacados 3     10
x
xxxxxxxxdon't shift or move xxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Use an Advanced Filter to paste filtered data in a second location.

Comment: @ScottCraner, using a filter would require me to click the drop down apply the filter. I am trying to automate it so that as soon as data is entered into a1-c1, it gets pushed accordingly to g1-i1. I was thinking it could eliminate the name into one area, and then pull from this one, and get rid of spaces.

Comment: Does the order of the food matter for the formula?  meaning, could it list: Lemons, then Avacados, then Apples, then Peaches?

Comment: @CRUTER preferably the order its being referenced. So how the example shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add an ID column to the foods, you could do the following using the `SMALL()` function:

[image: example of using the small() function in Excel]

`=IF(D3<>"",B3,"")`
`=IFERROR(SMALL($F$3:$F$8,ROW(C1)),"")`
`=VLOOKUP(H3,$B$3:$F$8,2,FALSE)`

**To Explain Further**

- The `SMALL()` function takes an array of numbers and will return the 1st smallest, 2nd smallest, or whatever smallest number you specify.  Because this example only has Food names, I had to add an `ID` column (column B) to get an array of numbers.
- Since we only want to view rows with data (amount & weight), I added another column `ID Formula` (column F) to only display the `ID` if the column has data.
- Now that we are only displaying ID's with data, we can use the `SMALL()` function to get the 1st smallest ID still showing, then the 2nd smallest ID still showing, and so on...  notice that I used the `ROW()` function to get 1,2,3...
- Lastly, I used a simple `VLOOKUP()` to add in the Food, Amount, and Weight for the respective ID's.

Comment: Can you please clarify this a bit more ex: where D3, or H3, or F3/8 comes in?

Comment: @Josh - I've added the 'To Explain Further' section.  Hope this helps!